# Cannot set dialog window's startup location in Prism for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I want to change the location of a dialog in its parent window. I have tried setting the `prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation` property as shown below, but this is not working.

```
 <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterOwner" /> <!--doesn't work-->
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal"/>

    </Style>
```

Comment: Improved title, clarity and formatting

Answer (score 0):

From your exemple, you are missing the last closing tag

```
<prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterOwner" />
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>

        </Style>
</prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
```

Tested and it works